# IE10 min-height not working

Tags: internet-explorer, web, css

I am unable to set 100% height of my DIVs despite of setting `min-height` for IE. Below are CSS and HTML respectively. Screenshot also attached.

As you can see , the scrollbar on left is not displaying 100%

[image]

**CSS**

```
body
{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#container
{
    background-color: "#FFF";
    width:100%;
    margin: 1%;
    overflow:auto;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;

}
#tree_register_abwab
{
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}
#content
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    width: 60%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.dynatree-title{
    font-size: 15px !important;
    font-style:normal;
    font-family: Arial !important;
    font-weight:100;
}
.question
{
    font-style:normal;
    color:blue;
    font-family:"Jameel Noori Nastaleeq"; color: rgb(191,22,38); font-size:15pt;
}
.answer
{
    font-style:normal;
    color:blue;
    font-family:"Jameel Noori Nastaleeq"; color:rgb(0,0,0); font-size:15pt;
    margin-top: 2%;
    display: block;
}
#pdficon
{
    margin-right: 1%;
}
.bold{font-weight:bold;font-size: 18pt;}
```

**HTML**

```
<html dir=rtl>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" >
         <link href="ui.dynatree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="tree-custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="search.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=all />
        <script src = "jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.dynatree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="search.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="tree_register_abwab"></div>
            <div id="content">
                <span id="question" class="question bold">
                </span>
                <span id="pdficon"><a title="  " href="#"><img src="pdf_icon.png" border="0" /></a></span>
                <span id="answer" class="answer">
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `html` to the top of the css file by changing the body part of the CSS to:

```
html, body
{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

You can also remove all of the `min-height` properties you have set as `height:100%` should cover it.

Comment: just because I did not include HTML tag IE skipped it?? Really?

Comment: yup! it tripped me up a few months back while testing an application in IE.

Comment: min-height:100px; was working in chrome but not in IE 11. After adding min-height: auto !important. It started working.

Answer (score 1):

IE completely ignores the min-height property instead taking the height declared as the minimum height (go figure!).

The trick is to set

```
height: auto !important;
```

on the element you are setting your min-height on.

eg:

```
.element {
min-height: 100px;
height: auto !important;
}
```

**NOTE:** *I tried this on an image element, YMMV.*

Comment: min-height:100px; was working in chrome but not in IE 11. After adding min-height: auto !important. It started working.